# How to add href "close" link to Fancybox modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to add href "close" link to Fancybox modal window? I want close Fancybox by click on href link inside modal window, in the same way as this done in Thickbox.
I dont want use separate javascript for this task, but instead want to modify Fancybox-1.3.4.js itself in order to get this functionality.

From Fancybox API, the following code will do this:

```
  <a href="javascript:$.fancybox.close()">close</a>
```

Need help and tips how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.fancybox.close();">Close</a>`

From fancybox.net look at the Inline - modal window example which has a Close text link

Answer (score 1):

the answer is covered in the fancybox tips & tricks so check here:
http://fancybox.net/blog

look for the first choice:

```
7. Custom title formating - lightbox style
```

Comment: I looked at p.7 "Custom title formatting - lightbox style": can I add javascript code at the end of main jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js and css?

Comment: I looked at p.7 "Custom title formatting - lightbox style": can I add this javascript code at directly after the end of main jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js code? 


function formatTitle(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
    return '<div id="tip7-title"><span><a href="javascript:$.fancybox.close()">close</a></span>' + (title && title.length ? '<b>' + title + '</b>' : '' ) + 'Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' of ' + currentArray.length + '</div>';
}

$(".tip7").fancybox({
 'showCloseButton' : false,
 'titlePosition'  : 'inside',
 'titleFormat'  : formatTitle
});

Comment: Would it be correct to omit unnecessary elements  like this? (as I need only close link)

      function formatTitle(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
    return '<div id="tip7-title"><span><a href="javascript:$.fancybox.close()">close</a></span>' + 'Image ' + '</div>';
}

Comment: @LexxLuxx - if you only need a close link i think it would be easier to just create a button that has the close fancybox function and then show it onStart event for the fancy, but i think that link i shared has an example like that.

Comment: Tried to add p.7 script from http://fancybox.net/blog to the end of  jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js code - not worked for me.

Comment: @LexxLuxx - make sure that you wrap it within a $(document).ready() event and that all the images/styles/java are installed correctly .

Comment: So custom code need be wrapped before  $(document).ready(function()? ...  $(document).ready(function() {
  $.fancybox.init();
 });

})(jQuery);

Comment: @LexxLuxx - need to be inserted after _$.fancybox.init(); }); })(jQuery);_ and wrapped in a new _$(document).ready(function(){});_

Comment: When click on thumbnail, it just open big image on new page, not fire up Fancybox.

Comment: the script and html sample: [http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/1/27/3255864/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.zip]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.fancybox.close();">close</a>
```